# Not being able to save image path to DB

Tags: laravel, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter application where I'm encountering an issue with creating a car through an API request. The API response indicates a redirection (status code 302), and the redirected URL is http://macbook-pro-van-jesse-2.local:8000. I'm having trouble understanding and handling this redirection properly.

**Code snippets:**

```
// api_services.dart

class ApiService {
  // ... (your existing code)

  createCar(String carName, String carDescription, String carImagePath, String screenPickerColor) async {
    try {
      requestSendData.fields['title'] = carName;
      requestSendData.fields['body'] = carDescription;
      requestSendData.fields['image_path'] = carImagePath;
      requestSendData.fields['background_color'] = "red";
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await requestSendData.send());
      String result = response.body;

      // Handling of the response...
      // (your existing code)

    } catch (error) {
      print('Error creating car: $error');
    } finally {
      requestSendData = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://macbook-pro-van-jesse-2.local:8000/api/cars'));
    }
  }
```

```
// ... (CarsController)
public function store(StoreCarsRequest $request)
    {
        //

        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'string',
            'body' => 'string',
            'background_color' => 'string',
            'image_path' => 'required|image',
        ]);

        $image = $this->saveImage($request->file('image_path'));
        $imagePath = Storage::put('public/cars/',$image->encode('png'));
        $car = Cars::create([
            'title' => $attrs['title'],
            'body' => $attrs['body'],
            'image_path' => $imagePath,
            'background_color' => $attrs['background_color'],
            'is_button' => true,
        ]);

        return response([
            'message' => 'Car successfully created',
            'car' => $car
        ], 200);
    }
```

After calling the createCar method, the API response contains a 302 status code, indicating a redirection. The redirected URL is http://macbook-pro-van-jesse-2.local:8000. I'm unsure how to handle this redirection correctly and would appreciate guidance on resolving this issue.

Additional Information:

The Flutter app is using the http package for API requests.
The API endpoint is expected to create a car and return a response with the created car details.
Any assistance or insights on properly handling this redirection in a Flutter application would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried reading the Laravel docs on the storage and I just think I am stuck on understanding, I made the symbolic link in the filesystem.php also the filesystem disk made the route, got the right directories when it is saving.

Comment: 302 in this sort of case typically indicates a you've a) got a validation error and b) the app thinks you're a web client. Send a `Accept: application/json` with your requests to get a 422 with JSON data about the error, instead.